# Android debug after killing the process(activity) manually

Tags: android, debugging

I want to debug my application and killing activity from DDMS to simulate the situation that low memory device kill the background activity to recycle memory. The process I use to kill the activity is:

1. Press the Home button;
2. Kill process from DDMS;
3. Restart the activity using Recent App.

I do find there is a bug in this activity, while I could not debug it in the 3rd step, because the Debug process will be terminated in 2nd step when the process is killed.

Does anyone know how to debug application in such situation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable "Don't keep activities" option in order to be able to debug through a situation in which the OS kills the activities as soon as you leave them to reclaim memory.

Settings --> Developer options --> Don't keep activities

Comment: Killing the whole thread and killing individual activities have different behaviors.